# Do two tasks parallely in retrofit and after that use their result in one task serially?

Tags: android, retrofit

Hello guys i am making an android app where i am using retrofit for networking calls now i am facing a problem where suppose i want to fetch a restaurant reviews in one retrofit request and its cover pic in second different retrofit request now my question is how to know when both request ended successfully i mean when they both end up successfully i want to set my adapter of the recyclerview which now has restaurant's cover pic at the top as well as reviews below it now can you all please tell me how to get it done.

**Actually my problem is somewhat like do two tasks parallely and now do something after they both end successfully in my case update my recyclerview adapter.**

Answer (score 0):

Define three flags `task1`, `task2` and `adapterSet`.

```
boolean firstCompleted = false;
boolean secondCompleted = false; 
boolean adapterSet = false;
```

In your first retrofit `success` callback set :

```
firstCompleted = true;

if(secondCompleted && firstCompleted && !adapterSet) {

adapterSet = true
//set your adapter here

}
```

In your second retrofit `success` callback :

```
secondCompleted = true;

if(secondCompleted && firstCompleted && !adapterSet) {

    adapterSet = true
    //set your adapter here

 }
```

This logic should work for your case.

Comment: actually i also thought somewhat like this but you have to use third task in a thread which is waiting when these two flags will come true ?? got my point ??

Comment: What is the third task for? Setting the adapter?

Comment: display the contents which i fetch from above two tasks in my recyclerview

Comment: Why do you need a thread to display UI stuff. Anyways android doesnt allows backgroung thread to make changes to the UI. I suggest making a simple method and calling that method if the condition is true.

Comment: do you how callback works it means firstly first task will execute then if it was succesful then second task but i want first and second task to run parallely got my point man

Comment: So you make both the retrofit calls. They were execute concurrently and above code will take care of setting the adapter to the recyclerview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92589/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-akash-singh).

Comment: and how will you do first and second concurrently because either i have to write second inside my first callback which will make them serial or how